# Fit paragraph inside the container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code to fit the paragraph with some conditions about font size and line-height but unfortunately I can't make the code to work properly: I think the infinite loop causes the issue.

Note: Do not run the code, your browser will crash because of the infinite while loop.

How can I fix the issue? What I'm missing?

Here is the code:

```js
const dialogueText = "To be successful, you have to use each day as an opportunity to improve, to be better, to get a little bit closer to your goals. It might sound like a lot of work and with a busy schedule, next to impossible. But the best part is, the more you accomplish, the more you'll want to do, the higher you'll want to reach. So as long as you have the hunger for success, you will always have the power within you to achieve it."; // Get from global

const answerSentence = document.getElementById("answerSentence");

generateDialogue();

function generateDialogue() {
  answerSentence.innerHTML = `<span>${dialogueText}</span>`;
  scaleFontVW();
}

function scaleFontVW() {
  let paragraph = document.getElementById("answerSentence");
  let paragraphContainer = document.getElementById("pc");
  let spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

  let style = window.getComputedStyle(spans[0], null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
  let fontSize = parseFloat(style);

  while (paragraph.scrollHeight >= paragraphContainer.clientHeight) {
    fontSize -= 1;
    paragraph.style.fontSize = fontSize + "vh";
    paragraph.style.lineHeight = fontSize * 0.4 + fontSize + "vh";
  }
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans Regular";
  src: url(OpenSans-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
}

html {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.containerAnswering {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 8.7vw;
  top: 25vh;
  height: 55vh;
  width: 82vw;
  /*outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;*/
}

.answerSentence-class {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Regular', sans-serif;
  color: #595959;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="pc" class="containerAnswering">
  <div id="answerSentence" class="answerSentence-class"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `>=` in the while loop is the cause of your endless loop. It happens because `paragraph.scrollHeight` is equal to `paragraphContainer.clientHeight` when the elements doesn't overflow.

I've started with a huge font size, and added `console.log(fontSize)`, so you can "see" it in action.

```js
const dialogueText = "To be successful, you have to use each day as an opportunity to improve, to be better, to get a little bit closer to your goals. It might sound like a lot of work and with a busy schedule, next to impossible. But the best part is, the more you accomplish, the more you'll want to do, the higher you'll want to reach. So as long as you have the hunger for success, you will always have the power within you to achieve it."; // Get from global

const answerSentence = document.getElementById("answerSentence");

generateDialogue();

function generateDialogue() {
  answerSentence.innerHTML = `<span>${dialogueText}</span>`;
  scaleFontVW();
}

function scaleFontVW() {
  let paragraph = document.getElementById("answerSentence");
  let paragraphContainer = document.getElementById("pc");
  let spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

  let style = window.getComputedStyle(spans[0], null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
  let fontSize = parseFloat(style);

  while (paragraph.scrollHeight > paragraphContainer.clientHeight) {
    console.log(fontSize);
    fontSize -= 1;
    paragraph.style.fontSize = fontSize + "vh";
    paragraph.style.lineHeight = fontSize * 0.4 + fontSize + "vh";
  }
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans Regular";
  src: url(OpenSans-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
}

html {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.containerAnswering {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 8.7vw;
  top: 25vh;
  height: 55vh;
  width: 82vw;
  /*outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;*/
}

.answerSentence-class {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Regular', sans-serif;
  color: #595959;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  font-size: 100vmin;
}
```

```html
<div id="pc" class="containerAnswering">
  <div id="answerSentence" class="answerSentence-class"></div>
</div>
```

And a version with `Window.requestAnimationFrame()` to actually see it in action:

```js
const dialogueText = "To be successful, you have to use each day as an opportunity to improve, to be better, to get a little bit closer to your goals. It might sound like a lot of work and with a busy schedule, next to impossible. But the best part is, the more you accomplish, the more you'll want to do, the higher you'll want to reach. So as long as you have the hunger for success, you will always have the power within you to achieve it."; // Get from global

const answerSentence = document.getElementById("answerSentence");

generateDialogue();

function generateDialogue() {
  answerSentence.innerHTML = `<span>${dialogueText}</span>`;
  scaleFontVW();
}

function scaleFontVW() {
  let paragraph = document.getElementById("answerSentence");
  let paragraphContainer = document.getElementById("pc");
  let spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

  let style = window.getComputedStyle(spans[0], null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
  let fontSize = parseFloat(style);

  scale(paragraph, paragraphContainer, fontSize);
}

function scale(paragraph, paragraphContainer, fontSize) {
  if(paragraph.scrollHeight > paragraphContainer.clientHeight) {
    fontSize -= 1;
    paragraph.style.fontSize = fontSize + "vh";
    paragraph.style.lineHeight = fontSize * 0.4 + fontSize + "vh";  
    
    requestAnimationFrame(() => scale(paragraph, paragraphContainer, fontSize));
  }
  
  
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans Regular";
  src: url(OpenSans-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
}

html {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.containerAnswering {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 8.7vw;
  top: 25vh;
  height: 55vh;
  width: 82vw;
  /*outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;*/
}

.answerSentence-class {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Regular', sans-serif;
  color: #595959;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: justify;
  text-justify: inter-word;
  font-size: 50vmin;
}
```

```html
<div id="pc" class="containerAnswering">
  <div id="answerSentence" class="answerSentence-class"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: or just remove `position: absolute;` from the child